# token authentication in django rest framewok is not working with digitalocean, but it is working perfectly in my local

Tags: django, rest, deployment, frameworks

I have deployed a django rest framework project on Digital-Ocean, everything works perfectly when I make a `post` and `get` request with postman software, but when make a `post` request to this `TestView` which is below, it is showing this error:

> Field 'id' expected a number but got <django.contrib.auth.models.AnonymousUser object at 0x7f10fecb2ed0>

From this line:

```py
score = Score.objects.get(user=request.user.id)
```

this is the TestView :

```py
class TestView(APIView):
    authentication_classes = [TokenAuthentication]
    def get(self, request):
        questions = Question.objects.all()
        questions_serializer = QuestionsSerializer(questions,many=True,context={'request': request})
        return Response(questions_serializer.data)
    
    def post(self, request):
        question_id = request.data.get('id')
        user_answer = request.data.get('answers')

        correct_answer = Answer.objects.filter(question=question_id, is_correct=True).values_list('answer', flat=True).first()

        if correct_answer is not None:
            if user_answer == correct_answer:
                try:
                    score = Score.objects.get(user=request.user.id)
                    print(self.user)
                    score.score += 1
                    score.save()
                except Score.DoesNotExist:
                    score = Score.objects.create(user=request.user, score=1)

                score_serializer = ScoreSerializer(score)
                return Response({'message': 'your answer was correct', 'score': score_serializer.data}, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
            else:
                return Response({'message': 'your answer was incorrect'}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
        else:
            return Response({'message': 'correct answer not found for this question'}, status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)
```

If I changed this line:

```py
score = Score.objects.get(user=request.user.id)
```

To this:

```py
score = Score.objects.get(user=1)
```

then it works.

I also printed the following:

```py
print(request.user)
print(request.user.id)
print(request.auth)
```

they are null, but in my local, the user instance is printed.

I wanted to get the user from the token that has been passed in the header, but when I run `print(request.user.id)`, it shows null.

Comment: The view you posted does not get authenticated when you make a request to it. Hence the error which shows anonymous user. See [TokenAuthentication](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/#tokenauthentication)